# Coefficient of the generating function $G(z)=\frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am seeking the coefficient $a_n$ of the generating function

$$G(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0} a_k z^k = \frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}$$

The combinatorial background of this question is to solve the recurrence

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4},\qquad (a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,2,4).$$

My first idea was to use that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ which after some expansion leads to

$$a_n = \sum_{k_1+2k_2+3k_3+4k_4 = n}\binom{k_1+k_2+k_3+k_4}{k_1}\binom{k_2+k_3+k_4}{k_2}\binom{k_3+k_4}{k_3}$$

At this point I have no idea how to continue. Looking for a recurrence for $a_n$ would mean to run in circles. I feel that another combinatorial technique is needed, which I dont know. Any ideas?

Comment: see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+1%2F%281-x-x%5E2-x%5E3-x%5E4%29 and http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C4%2C8%2C15%2C29&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Have you tried writing $(1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4)\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k = 1$, and expanding to get something of the form $a_0+\cdots+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k-a_{k+1} - \cdots - a_{k+4}) z^k = 0$, to get both a (linear) recurrence relation on the $a_k$'s and the initial conditions?

Comment: @ESSAM thanks, now we know it is the tetranacci numbers.

Comment: @flonk you are welcome

Comment: @ClementC. well, I started with the recurrence, it is $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}+a_{k-4}$ with $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,2,4)$.

Comment: You may get a simpler expression by rewriting $G(z)$ as $\displaystyle \frac{1-z }{1-2z+ z^5 } $. Another possible direction is to decompose $G(z)$ into partial fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\left\{z_i\right\}_{i=1}^4$ be the roots of the polynomial in the denominator. Note that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4} = \frac{-1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^4 (z-z_i)} = 
\sum\limits_{p=1}^4 \frac{-1}{z-z_p} \cdot \left(\prod\limits_{q\neq p} \frac{1}{z_p-z_q}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now clearly :
\begin{equation}
a_k = \frac{1}{k!} \frac{d^k}{d z^k}\left. \left(  \frac{1}{1-\sum\limits_{j=1}^4 z^j} \right) \right|_{z=0} =
\sum\limits_{p=1}^4 \frac{1}{z_p^{k+1}} \cdot \left(\prod\limits_{q\neq p} \frac{1}{z_p-z_q}\right) = \left(1,1,2,4,8,15,29,56,108,208,401,\cdots\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

The Fibonacci sequence given by $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ has $\dfrac{z}{1-z-z^2}$ as generating function.

By analogy,
$\dfrac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}$ is related to the recurrence
$
a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}
$.

A closed expression for this recurrence involves the roots of ${1+z+z^2+z^3=z^4}$.

The exact expression will depend on the initial values $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$.

Comment: It should be the roots of $1-z-z^2-z^3=z^4$, right?

Comment: @flonk, no: you want solutions of the form $a_n=\alpha^n$.

Comment: @flonk Yes the roots of $1-z-z^2-z^3=z^4$ (that is, the denominator of $G$...).

Comment: well, it seems undecidable, as both roots are connected by $x\mapsto 2-x$. However, is your point that the $a_n$ have no closed form, simply because the fourth order root has none?

Comment: Aren't the initial values already specified as part of the generating function?  e.g., $a_0 = G(0)$, $a_1=G'(0)$, and so on.

Comment: @RonGordon yes, the above formula is only valid for $(a_0,...,a_3)=(1,1,2,4)$, in general you need to replace $G(z)\mapsto G(z)+(a_0-1)+(a_1-1)z+(a_2-2)z^2+(a_3-4)z^3$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another variant to extract the coefficients $a_n$ resulting in a different formula.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}&=\frac{1}{1-z(1+z+z^2+z^3)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-z\frac{1-z^4}{1-z}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1-z}{1-2z+z^5}\\
> &=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k(2-z^4)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=(1-z)\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{l}{k}(-1)^lz^{4l}2^{k-l}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (2) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem.

> Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series we obtain from (3) 
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty &z^k\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(-1)^lz^{4l}2^{k-l}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n [z^{n-k}]\sum_{l=0}^k\binom{k}{l}(-1)^lz^{4l}2^{k-l}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n[z^k]\sum_{l=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{l}(-1)^lz^{4l}2^{n-k-l}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor}[z^{4k}]\sum_{l=0}^{n-4k}\binom{n-4k}{l}(-1)^lz^{4l}2^{n-4k-l}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor}\binom{n-4k}{k}(-1)^k2^{n-5k}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we apply the rule $[z^p]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$ and set the upper limit of the outer sum to $n$ since the power of $z^{n-k}$ is non-negative.
- In (5) we change the order of summation $k\rightarrow n-k$.
- In (6) we observe that due to the factor $z^{4l}$ only multiples of $4$ contribute to the coefficient of $z^n$.
- In (7) we select the coefficient with $k=l$ accordingly.

> Respecting the factor $(1-z)$ in (3) we conclude from (3) and (7) the coefficients $a_n$ of the series $\frac{1}{1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}$
>   are given by
>   \begin{align*}
> \qquad\qquad\color{blue}{a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/4}\rfloor}\left[\binom{n-4k}{k}-\frac{1}{2}\binom{n-4k-1}{k}\right](-1)^k2^{n-5k}}\qquad\qquad 
> \color{blue}{n\geq 0}
> \end{align*}
>
> In general we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \qquad\qquad&[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z-z^2-\cdots-z^p}=[z^n]\frac{1-z}{1-2z+z^{p+1}}\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/p}\rfloor}\left[\binom{n-pk}{k}-\frac{1}{2}\binom{n-pk-1}{k}\right](-1)^k2^{n-(p+1)k}\qquad\ \  n\geq 0
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Following your comments above: once you have the recurrence relation $a_k = a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+a_{k-3}+a_{k-4}$ and the initial condition $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)=(1,1,2,4)$, then you can solve the system by writing 
$$X_k = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{k}\\
a_{k+1}\\
a_{k+2}\\
a_{k+3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so that it amounts to solving $$
X_{k+1} = A X_k
$$
with the initial condition
$$
X_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
2\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To do that, first you can [diagonalize $A$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize%20%5B%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%5D&t=crmtb01), to get $A=P^{-1}\Delta P$ for some diagonal matrix $\Delta$; leading to $X_k = P^{-1} \Delta^k P X_0$, which once written out gives a closed-form expression for $X_k$ (and thus $a_k$).

Comment: This rediscovers in a somewhat convoluted way that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the denominator in the ratio to be expanded. The next step will require to factor this polynomial--so much so that one can prefer the more direct route of decomposing G itself, instead of making what might be somewhat uncharitably described as circles.

Comment: @Did: yes... basically, that is how we introduced this result, back in school. (And to this day, it's still the most intuitive way I found to understand the result, and the way that sticks to my mind.)

Comment: @ClementC. thanks, but as I tried to say above, that recurrence is not the solution, it is how I *came to* the above question.

Comment: @flonk: solving the recurrence (which the answer above explains how to do, in a slightly cumbersome way), though, will give the value and closed-form expression of the $a_k$'s. Which *is* what you are looking for, isn't it?

Comment: @ClementC. yes, but only if you can do the diagonalization in a closed form, which requires the closed form for a 4th order polynomial. This will be the polynomial of the denominator of $G(z)$ and is the main problem of the question (note that the partial fraction decomposition of $G(z)$ would lead directly to $a_k$ and needs exactly these roots).

Comment: @flonk: fair enough -- I hadn't understood your problem was there (i.e., in computing the roots themselves, rather than just expressing the solution in terms of these roots).